# Can't get deleted occurrences of a repeating event from outlook calendar

Tags: outlook, microsoft-graph-api, microsoft-graph-calendar

I am trying to figure out how to get deleted occurrences of a repeating event. I am syncing with the delta token, and that gets me most of what I need, but if I have a recurring event in outlook and I delete one of the events in the series (not the whole series) the delta does not return the deleted event and I don't want to store all the recurring events and then query for the difference.

Comment: Can you add a bit more information on the api call that you are currently trying as well as if you are using any specific languages or packages to access the api that may be relevant to the question? Also what version of the API are you using 1.0 or beta?

Comment: I am using the graph .net sdk, so my call looks like this 
```options = new List<QueryOption> { new QueryOption("$deltatoken", _deltaToken) };
delta = await _graphClient.Me.CalendarView.Delta().Request(options).GetAsync();
``` where options includes a start and end time

Answer (score 0):

This looks like a bug. Specifically, it looks like removing an instance from a series is failing to show up as a change or delete (I'm actually not sure which I expect it to be).

I recommend posting this to [Graph's Issues page](https://github.com/microsoftgraph/microsoft-graph-docs/issues) so it gets in front of the proper folks from Exchange/Outlook.

Comment: Thanks, thats sort of what I was worried about, just wondering if someone else had run into this issue and found a way to make it work.

Comment: @XanderJPN50 Can you share the details of how you have handled this?